# question on factors of numbers

Tags: number-theory

Let N be a positive integer
And N=$(a^p)(b^q)$
Where a and b are primes
Where a and b are distinct 
Then prove that sum of the divisors or factor of N is

=$$(a^{p+1}-1)(b^{q+1}-1)/(a-1)(b-1)$$

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ prime?

Comment: Yes, that *is* an important question!

Comment: Yes a and b are primes

Comment: Are a and b also distinct? You really shoudl specify these things before giving us homework problems to solve.

Comment: They will obviously distinct that why I gave 2 different value a and b .....use common sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\dfrac{a^{p+1}-1}{a-1}\cdot{}\dfrac{b^{q+1}-1}{b-1}=(1+a+a^2+\cdots{}+a^p)(1+b+b^2+\cdots{}+b^q).$$

What does each of the term constitute?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a and b are prime:

Hint:  Here the divisors:

$1, a, a^2.....,a^p$

$b, ab, a^2b, .....,a^pb$

$b^2, ab^2, a^2b^2, .....,a^pb^2$

......

$b^q, ab^q, a^2b^q,......,a^pb^q$